# why declaration of methods in different style different results in scala

Tags: function, scala, methods, types, call

Below are two methods that are declared in different style. Both are doing the same work. I am wondering, why

1. different syntax is required to check type of function (yellow
   block)
2. different syntax is required to call function (green block)
3. declaration of both methods on scala repl gives different results
   (red block)

> Also, please suggest, which one is the preferred way to declare
>   methods or are there any special use cases for both the styles of
>   method declaration?

[image]

---

**Edit 1:**

Below are the commands from screenshot :-

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def add(x:Int, y :Int): Int = {x+y}
add: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> def sum = (x:Int, y:Int) => {x+y}
sum: (Int, Int) => Int

scala> :t add
<console>:12: error: missing arguments for method add;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       add
       ^

scala> :t add(_, _)
(Int, Int) => Int

scala> :t sum
(Int, Int) => Int

scala> add
<console>:12: error: missing arguments for method add;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       add
       ^

scala> add(_, _)
res1: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> sum
res2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

---

**Edit 2:**

**@Shadowlands**

i have read on [dzone](http://dzone.com/articles/revealing-scala-magician%E2%80%99s), that states "when a function is expected but a method is provided, it will be automatically converted into a function. This is called the ETA expansion.".

Now, if ETA takes care to convert your methods to function. Is it really required to use sum style, because it looks like an additional overhead of Function<> object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between method and function in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Comment: Please copy the text here instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, `add` is a function that takes two `Int` arguments and returns an `Int` result, while `sum` is a 0-argument function that returns a new function that, in turn, takes two `Int` arguments and returns an `Int` result. Indeed, `sum` could readily be defined as:

```
def sum = add _
```

As to which way to define your functions, this depends on how it is to be used. Generally, use the `add` style most of the time, as it is easier to understand and work with. If, however, you will be passing the function as an argument to another function, then the `sum`-style formulation can be more convenient and may convey more of your intent on how the function is expected to be used.

Comment: i have read https://dzone.com/articles/revealing-scala-magician%E2%80%99s, that "when a function is expected but a method is provided, it will be automatically converted into a function. This is called the ETA expansion.". Now, if ETA takes care to convert your methods to function. Is it really required to use sum style, because it looks like an additional overhead of Function<> object.

Comment: @rits No, it certainly isn't required! There just may be times when it is useful as, for example, an indicator of how you expect it to be used, or you might be defining an implicit value to then be passed on automatically as an implicit argument to an appropriately-typed function.

Comment: @rits Hmm, comments aren't really meant for whole multiline examples, so I'll try something brief (and rather contrived). Imagine a method defined as `def operate(x:Int, y :Int)(implicit op: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = op(x, y)`. You might then set up your code to read a flag and use it to decide which op you want used, eg: `implicit val op = if (flag) add _ else someOtherOp _`, then later when you call `operate(x,y)`, the method will execute the implicit operation you selected earlier.

Comment: As of now, i don't know the concept of implicit keyword. Probably, after learning about this keyword, i would be able to understand your example. If fails to understand, i will open a new question on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how REPL is implemented. The code that you type is wrapped in `object`. Thus your `def add` becomes method of this object, while `def sum` is a method that returns `Function`. When you are addressing `add` like this: `add(_, _)` you are addressing method, while when you are addressing `sum` as `sum` you are addressing result of sum's execution, which is function.

Differences between methods and functions are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

PS. Try to check the type of `sum _`

Comment: "Try to check the type of sum _". this line really helped me to understand the concept. Upvoting your answer. Thanks.